# ng test with watcher is very slow after recompile

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Running `ng test` works smoothly and quickly the first pass (2-3 secs for 70 tests). But then when a change triggers the watcher to recompile, `ng test` will take 1-2 secs to go through *each* test, making the whole process take exponentially longer.

Is this unique to our (still relatively small) project or do others experience this?  Is there a solution, or even just a way to diagnose what's causing the slowdown?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: We have the same issue here.... do you already have a solution?

Comment: We haven't found a solution yet @AndreasLöw

Comment: We have had the same issue, only with PhantomJS (no chrome)...anyone else having similar ultra slow test runs? Our CI builds take some 15-30 minutes to run depending on the size of the test suite.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... found the solution to this.

If you Chrome window is visible on the screen (at least 1 pixel of it) it runs at full speed.

As soon as Chrome is not visible (hidden by some other window or minimized) the tests are slow.

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues/81

Comment: You're correct, but this should be handled with the flag that is passed into the `karma-chrome-launcher`

`'--disable-background-timer-throttling',`